# Use Route component and Route children in same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner to react js and now I am practicing routes but stuck in an nested routes error below:

> You should not use Route component and Route children in the same route; `<Route children>` will be ignored.

By above it can be seen route and children component cannot be used in the same route which I had, so how can I fix my below code so it can work:

```
  const About=(props)=>(
   <div>
    {props.children}
    <h2>About</h2>
   </div>
  );


 const Cityimage=()=>(

        <h1>In City</h1>
 );

 const Sportsimage=()=>(
   <h2>In Sports</h2>
 );

ReactDOM.render(

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />

        <Route  path="/about" component={About}>
             <Route  path="city" component={Cityimage}/>
             <Route  path="sport" component={Sportsimage}/>
        </Route>

    </Switch>
</Router>
   ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have a parent route About and its two children route city and sport. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

can you tried?

```
<Route  path="/about" component={About}/>
<Route  path="/about/city" component={Cityimage}/>
<Route  path="/about/sport" component={Sportsimage}/>
```